# rails3 globalize3 migrate_data problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

data migrates but all cyrillic symbols are replaced with "?". Everything allright with latin sybols.

Comment: Whats the encoding of your old data and of your new database?
Check you have `encoding: utf8` for your current environment in database.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with setting charset in mysql manually.